# Bootstrap | Inline element inside same div

Tags: html, css, mdbootstrap

i have a `<div class="col-md-12"></div>` i want the two element stay on to text-align:left and another to the right, but i want, when the div is seen in mobile vision, that an element does not go below and one above but are aligned how can I do?

example:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p style="text-align: left;" id="element_one">1</p>
    <p style="text-align: right;" id="element_two">1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Bootstrap's Float class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/), not just aligning of the text element.
In your case it will be:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: aqua">
        <span class="float-md-left">1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: palevioletred">
        <span class="float-md-right">2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Live example:**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: aqua">
      <span class="float-sm-left">1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: palevioletred">
      <span class="float-sm-right">2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

format using bootstrap grid structure

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 text-left">
            <p id="element_one">1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <p  id="element_two">1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Text alignment:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
      Left content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
      Right content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you can find more info and examples: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/utilities/text/#text-alignment